# How convert sql join query into django queryset

Tags: python, sql, django, django-filter

I am trying to write django sql query on two tables i.e. table1, table2 and display query data in table3. Could someone show how to convert the following SQL join query to the Django queryset.

```
Sql query

INSERT INTO table3(project_name,task_name,set_status,date,created_by)
SELECT table1.projects_name, table2.task_name,'pending' AS set_status, table1.created_date, table2.created_by_id
FROM table1
RIGHT JOIN table2 ON (table1.id = table2.projects_name_id AND table1.created_by_id = table2.created_by_id) 

Model

class Table1(models.Model):
    projects_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created_date  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, blank=True)
    created_by    = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="projectcreatby", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Table2(models.Model):
    projects_name = models.ForeignKey(Projects, related_name="projects", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    task_name     = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created_by    = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="taskcreateby", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Table3(models.Model):
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    task_name    = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    set_status   = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    date         = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, blank=True)
    created_by   = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Comment: Looking at your models what you what you need is not a join but to normalize your database schema. Research a bit on database normalization.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Yes, I want to filter my database tables and that filter data insert into third table with the help of Django query set.